# increment the lowest char to the highest char of a string

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method where it takes the lowest char in the string and increments it to the highest char in the string but, the final string cannot include any of the characters that were in the original string (ex: input:"zoo" output:"pqrstuvwxy", input:"hello" output:"fgijkmn".  I have tried to do by sorting but it is not working.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MissingLetters {
    public static String GetMissingLetters(String testString){
        char[] chars=testString.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        String newWord=new String(chars);
        char[] a = new char[newWord.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<=newWord.length();i++){
            a[i]=newWord.charAt(i);
            char s=newWord.charAt(0);
            char t=newWord.charAt(newWord.length());
            for(char c=s;c<=t;c++){
                newWord=Character.toString(c);
            }
        }
        return newWord;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String n=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print(GetMissingLetters(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please show some sample input and output.

Comment: Can you give an example of sourde data and what you would like to get? I do not really undesrtand your description.

Comment: suppose i input the string: "hello", the output should be "efghijklmno", as it goes from the lowest char to the highest char in the string

Answer (score 0):

The below code would work for you if you are using all small or capital letters. If your want to use mixed case of letters and dont want symbols, then u have to change the logic for the loop and appending( commented as //1 and //2).

public class MissingLetters {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "hello";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String newString = "";
     for(char ch = chars[0] ; ch <= chars[chars.length-1] ; ch++ ){//1
         newString = newString+ch;// 2
   }
     System.out.println("New String is :"+newString);

}
```

}